# Play Framework: Rendering PDF using PDF module makes call to generate dynamic images 3 times each

Tags: java, playframework, pdf-generation

I have a template that can be rendered as either html or pdf.  The pdf version is being created using the PDF module.

The template has a call to generate a dynamic image like this:

```
<img src="@@{MyController.generateImage()}">
```

When rendering the template as html, the `generateImage()` method gets called **once**.

When rendering the template as pdf, the `generateImage()` method gets called **three times**.  Even though the method is called three times, the image only appears once in the pdf.

Does anyone have any ideas why pdf'ing the template would cause the `generateImage()` method to be called so many times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using PDF module 0.7 and upgraded to 0.9 and it resolved my issue.  I had previously been unable to upgrade to 0.9 due to conflicting libraries being used by my project and the PDF module, however, as a test I just removed the need for the conflicting library temporarily to see if 0.9 fixed the multiple call issue which it did.

Answer (score 0):

If you have eclipsify your play (play.bat eclipsify), then run "play.bat run" and then right click the launcher for debug one in eclipse folder and put a breakpoint there, you can probably figure it out.  The play code has not been too bad as of yet except for getting into some of the groovy stuff, which ou will see with that example a "little" of but for the most part you can skip around in the stack trace and figure out why it is called 3 times.

later,
Dean